# How to use DTE in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, envdte

I am trying to use PowerShell to automate the process of creating an n-tier solution based on a seed (think EDMX file or DbContext) configuration. I want to be able to open a skeleton solution, get the active instance, and populate project files with auto-generated code.

I'm trying to transcode the example provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/68shb4dw.aspx) to powershell, however, I am getting errors.

Here is the PowerShell code I am testing:

First, I execute a little function to reference the DTE assemblies.

```
$libs = "envdte.dll", "envdte80.dll", "envdte90.dll", "envdte100.dll"
function LoadDTELibs {
    param(
        $path = "\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"
    )

    Process {
        $libs |
            ForEach {
                $dll = Join-Path "$env:ProgramFiles\$path" $_

                if(-not (Test-Path $dll)) {
                    $dll = Join-Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\$path" $_
                }

                Add-Type -Path $dll -PassThru | Where {$_.IsPublic -and $_.BaseType} | Sort Name
            }
    }
}


LoadDTELibs
```

Then, I try to create a object to reference the result of calling `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0")`

```
PS> $dte = New-Object -ComObject EnvDTE80.DTE2

New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At line:1 char:8
+ $dte = New-Object -ComObject EnvDTE80.DTE2
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

or:

```
PS> $dte = New-Object EnvDTE80.DTE2

New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type EnvDTE80.DTE2.
At line:1 char:8
+ $dte = New-Object EnvDTE80.DTE2
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Finally, this does not work either:

```
PS> [EnvDTE80.DTE2]$dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0")

Cannot convert the "System.__ComObject" value of type "System.__ComObject#{04a72314-32e9-48e2-9b87-a63603454f3e}" to type "EnvDTE80.DTE2".
At line:1 char:1
+ [EnvDTE80.DTE2]$dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

So, my question is, how do you use DTE from PowerShell? More specifically, how do you cast the result of calling GetActiveObject to type EnvDTE.DTE2?

Comment: I believe NuGet's [TypeWrapper](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/46278ab10d9a#src/VsConsole/PowerShellHost/Utils/TypeWrapper.cs) class works around this same issue. (**Caution:** Apache-licensed code owned by the Outercurve Foundation)

Comment: This is a great suggestion, and, lots of insight was provided by reviewing this code. However, it seems I have found a simple alternative. As you will see in my follow up answer, PowerShell handles the process a bit differently, so, casting as described on MSDN is not required.

Comment: If you are using the package manager console in VS, the current instance's EnvDTE is already provided by the `$dte` variable.

Comment: @bricelam https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.14/src/VsConsole/PowerShellHost/Utils/TypeWrapper.cs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a simple answer by playing with the idea in ISE for a little while.

Basically, the call to GetActiveObject returns a COM object, which can be used directly in PowerShell. After executing LoadDTELibs, you can get an instance of DTE by calling GetActiveObject and then refer to the result directly.

So...

```
PS> $dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0")
```

Then:

```
PS> $dte.solution.Create("D:\Testing", "Acme.sln")
PS> $dte.solution.SaveAs("D:\Testing\Acme.sln")
```

I'm not 100% sure, because I don't know PowerShell or COM all that well, but I think you don't really have to worry about releasing the COM instance.

Comment: It was [this](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_com.htm) article which provided the clues which were helpful in finding the answer.

Comment: "After executing LoadDTELibs" - How did you execute this?

Comment: With this code I can't reach the part of the api to do remote debugging though, like [Debugger2.Transports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.debugger2.transports?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Answer (score 2):

For VS 2017 it is as follows:

```
$dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Running Visual Studio 2019, I've been able to start the debugger with the 'VisualStudio.DTE' COM interface (without the version):

```
#Get the ProcessID from an AppPool's worker process: 
[int] $ProcessId = ([xml] (& "$env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list wp /xml /apppool.name:"DefaultAppPool")).appcmd.WP."WP.NAME"

# Start the debugger, attached to that ProcessID
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('VisualStudio.DTE').Debugger.LocalProcesses | 
       ? {$_.ProcessID -eq $ProcessId} | %{$_.Attach()}
```

Previously it was necessary to specify the version.

Comment: This is a great tip for getting a specific IIS App Pool by name